# My GoogleMap does not Work in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-maps

I've started to work on HTML5 and PHP but i had a problem about Inserting google map inside of my php file. I'm going to put sample codes i've written. Maybe anyone has a solution for my situation.

In my first file which is 'index.html' I have a input and a button which will submit and send input to php file. The code that i've written for this is shown below.

```
<form action="deneme.php" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="searchtxt" id="searchtxt" placeholder="Write something to search"></br>
                <div align="center">
                <input type="submit" name="locationbtn"  data-icon= "search" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="a" data-inline="true" value="Find Location"></button> 
                </div>
            </form>
```

In my 'deneme.php' file the codes are just like that.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>



<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bgcolor.css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
function TestGeo()
{
     if (navigator.geolocation) 
        {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( TestMap, error, {maximumAge: 30000, timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true} );
    }
    else
    {
          alert("Sorry, but it looks like your browser does not support geolocation.");
    }
}

var map;
 function TestMap(position)
 {
       // Define the coordinates as a Google Maps LatLng Object
       var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

       // Prepare the map options
       var mapOptions =
      {
                  zoom: 10,
                  center: coords,
                  mapTypeControl: false,
                  navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL},
                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        // Create the map, and place it in the map_canvas div
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

        // Place the initial marker
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: coords,
                  map: map,
                  title: "Your current location!"
        });

function error() {
        alert("Cannot locate user");
        }
</script>   
</head>


  <body onload="TestGeo();">
<?php 
    $t=date("H");
    $search=$_REQUEST['searchtxt'];

        if($t<"18"){
      echo ("<br/>Have a good day " . $search . " !");
    }
        else{
      echo ("<br/>Have a good night " . $search . " !") ;       
    flush();
    flush();
        }

      ?>
</div>
            <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 85%;  border-right: 1px solid #666666; border-bottom: 1px solid #666666; border-top: 1px solid #666666; border-left: 1px solid #AAAAAA;" align="center">
    </div>
```

The main problem is my deneme.php file is not loading google map  when i click to Submit button, but i have the input value entered in index.html printed in deneme.php file. I've tried to solve problem by changing button from `<input>` to `<button href="#deneme.php" type="button" name="locationbtn"  data-icon= "search" onclick="location.href='deneme.php'" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="a" data-inline="true">Find Location</button>` after doing this, I could not get the input in html file printed in php file. But google map works in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.html` files are generally NOT processed through the PHP interpreter, and just sent out as plain text. If you hit your submit button, and do a "view source" on the location.html page, you'll probably see the raw PHP code embedded in there. Try renaming it to `location.php`, changing your form to point to this new filename, and try again.